# Make Touch Screen Ignore Labels for Window Scrolling in Winforms App

Tags: winforms, label, touchscreen, scrollable

I have a winforms app that has a tab page with a lot of labels, textboxes, and other controls.  Some users are running this app on tablet PCs.  The problem is that it's hard to find a screen area in the tab large enough to "grab on to" in order to scroll the tabs contents up and down with your finger.  You have to find a spot in between all the labels and other controls.  I don't have the option of moving any of these controls to another tab and don't have much real estate to work with.

Since the labels are not interactive and only display text, I thought it could be good if there was some way to make them ignore touch input so that the user can use the label areas to "grab on to" and scroll the window.

Is there any way to make labels behave this way?

Thanks in advance...

EDIT:

Per request below.

IDE is Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop

Platform is x86

The Framework is .net 4.5

UI is primarily Windows 8 running on a tablet PC

Comment: please provide full information. visual studio version, supported platform version, framework version,UI, etc.

Comment: Is it really a label, or is it a textbox widget?

Comment: @Nimesh - Please see edits above...

Comment: @RawBean = Yes, it is labels to which I am referring...